# Populate Google Sheet row with an array using Google Script – Incorrect range width

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a very basic question – I am trying to populate a first empty row in Google Sheets with a hard-coded array (I will then work on populating it with data pulled from another sheet).

I keep getting the "Incorrect range width, was 14 but should be 1."

I am trying to do it using the following code:

```
function populateSaleData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var saleData = new Array()
  saleData.push(["43376","John","Product","30","Dollars","30","yes","5","card","712.5","Adam","xyz@gmail.com","US","XYZ123456"])

  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sales');
  var lastFilledRowInColumnA = getLastPopulatedRow(destSheet.getRange('A:A').getValues());
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(lastFilledRowInColumnA+1,1);
  destRange.setValues(saleData);
};

function getLastPopulatedRow(data) {
  for (var i=data.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    for (var j=0;j<data[0].length;j++)
      if (data[i][j]) return i+1;
  return 0;
};
```

I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: I think that the reason of the issue is at ``destSheet.getRange(lastFilledRowInColumnA+1,1)``. In this case, each element of 2 dimensional array is required to be "1". So how about modifying to ``destSheet.getRange(lastFilledRowInColumnA+1,1,saleData.length,saleData[0].length)``? The reference is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns).

Comment: This worked, thank you! (and thanks for directing me to the reference)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was solved. Can you post the answer and accept it? I think that it will be useful for users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tanaike's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52618101/populate-google-sheet-row-with-an-array-using-google-script-incorrect-range-wi#comment92170379_52618101) resolved my issue:

I think that the reason of the issue is at `destSheet.getRange(lastFilledRowInColumnA + 1, 1)`. In this case, each element of 2-dimensional array is required to be "1". So how about modifying to `destSheet.getRange(lastFilledRowInColumnA + 1, 1, saleData.length, saleData[0].length)`? The method reference is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns).